# React (Next js): Optimize network waterfall and respect pure components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, architecture

I'm planning to do an appointment manager. Therefore I have the following basic architecture which I'd like you to evaluate:
[BasicConceptUML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnIl0.png)

I am still learning React. My goal is to have clean code. I want to share my thoughts so I can learn from your experiences!

**Requirements**

- User can select days of interests
- Fetch appointment data for days of interests from DB
- Manipulate appointment data

**Fetching Data:**
There are two locations where I could fetch the data:
*1. Inside Table 2. Inside Colum*

I decided to fetch the data in the *Table* to prevent to many requests to the DB.
I therefore use an *Effect Hook* to make the fetch call.
In detail there will actually be a week selector in the *Tabel Component* to choose the week of interests. So even if the Data Fetch will be event driven I think making the call inside an *Effect Hook* is best practice because I don't want to fetch the data on every render. And it should fetch some data when component mounts the first time. Right?

**Manipulating the Appointments:**
There will be a *Column Component* for every day with its respective *Appointments*.

It recieves the *Appointments* from *Table*.
The user should be able to change the data of the Appointments. For example changing the date.
To prevent side effects a Component needs to be pure. So I think I have to declare the *changeAppointmentDateFunction* inside Table and not inside Column. This should also solve the problem of showing the Appointment in the *new* Column because I will be changing the State AppointmentsForThisDays. Right?

So this are my basic ideas how to implement my appointment manager. Would you do it similary or do I totaly drift away from best practice next js programming?